# Which character died at the end of "The Prestige"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-prestige

Probably goes without saying, but big spoiler alert!

The big plot twist of the movie "The Prestige" is that

> "Borden" is actually two people, Borden, and his brother/assistant "Fallon."

At the end of the movie,

> Angier frames Borden for murdering him, and Borden/Fallon is hung. Then Fallon/Borden comes back and shoots and kills Angier, burns his workshop down, and leaves with his daughter, Jess.

It just occurred to me, that I don't actually know which character dies at the end. Is it

> Borden (The husband of Sarah, and the Father of Jess) dies, and Fallon avenges him and takes care of Jess

or

> Fallon (Sarah's brother in law, Jess's uncle) dies, and Borden avenges him and takes care of Jess?

I had always assumed it was the first, but [Wikipedia's explanation of the plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prestige_(film)#Plot) states that it is the second. Is there any concrete evidence either way?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to tell who is who in each scene?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/4470/49)

Comment: It's a dupe. That one answers this one completely.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Can I close my own question as a dupe of that one, or do I not have enough rep?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem now that a close vote has been cast I believe you should have the option to "approve" the close without waiting for any more.

Comment: Um, how is that a duplicate at all? This question seems way more specific and hard to answer by the much more general and likely incompletely answered older question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson a bullet point in the accepted answer mentions which Bolden dies.